# Unity 4 Web Player offline installation - is it possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, web

I would like to know if there is any way available to install Unity web player to a PC that is not connected to the internet.

The official installer installs an ActiveX component, and a NSAPI DLL and once these are installed the plugin will try to fetch the player and Mono from the internet and install them.

Answer (score 2):

Download the full version plugin from this URL, works for me!
http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/UnityWebPlayerFull.exe

Answer (score 0):

From the Unity documentation it should be possible.

> If the Offline Deployment option is enabled for a webplayer then the UnityObject.js file (used to interface the player with the host page) will be placed alongside the player during the build. This enables the player to work with the local script file even when there is no network connection; normally, UnityObject.js is downloaded from Unity's webserver so as to make use of the latest version.

See the section about web player offline deployment on the unity documentation page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html

Comment: I am actually referring to installing the Unity Web Player browser plugin without being connected to the internet. Unity does not offer an offline installer for the web player for a PC that has never connected to the internet (in my case, it is a requirement).

Comment: There is an offline installer for download on their website: http://unity3d.com/webplayer/

Comment: This installer can be downloaded but requires internet connection to install the ActiveX component and DLL. Unfortunately this doesn't work if the machine is _always_ offline.

Comment: Ow, too bad. In that case maybe have a chat with the Unity support guys.